# How to use LIKE/CONTAINS query for double value in realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm LIKE/CONTAINS works for string values. How to search Double value for that works same as LIKE/CONTAINS

```
public class ProductModel: Object {
     @objc dynamic var id: String? = ""
     @objc dynamic var amount: Double = 0.0
}

func searchProductByAmount(searchValue:Double) -> Results<ProductModel> {
    let realm = RealmManager.Product
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "amount CONTAINS %@", searchAmount)
    let products = realm.objects(ProductModel.self).filter(predicate)
    return products
}
```

**Product Model Records:**

1. id:"1", amount:10.00
2. id:"2", amount:100.00
3. id:"3", amount:101.00
4. id:"3", amount:200.00

searchProductByAmount(searchValue:10) // should return 10, 100, 101 records

Comment: This should be of some help if you haven't discovered it already: https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: Can you clarify what the query is supposed to return? Only amounts that *start with* 10 or that *contain* 10? i.e. 101234 would be returned but 121034 or 1101 would not be?

Comment: @Jay I am looking for the query to work as a LIKE operator in SQL for double value.
For suppose if I type 1 will return me 10,100,101 product model objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your double values as strings and use LIKE and CONTAINS.

```
public class ProductModelS: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var amount: String = "0.0"

    convenience init(id: String?, amount: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.amount = amount
    }
}


class ProductModelTests: XCTestCase {

    func testDoubleAsString() {
        let models = [
            ProductModelS(id: UUID().uuidString, amount: String(format: "%.02f", 10.00)),
            ProductModelS(id: UUID().uuidString, amount: String(format: "%.02f", 100.00)),
            ProductModelS(id: UUID().uuidString, amount: String(format: "%.02f", 101.00)),
            ProductModelS(id: UUID().uuidString, amount: String(format: "%.02f", 200.00)),
        ]

        let config = Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: UUID().uuidString)

        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(models)
            }

            let containsResults = realm.objects(ProductModelS.self)
                .filter("amount CONTAINS %@", "\(10)")
            let likeResults = realm.objects(ProductModelS.self)
                .filter("amount LIKE %@", "*\(10)*")
            print("CONTAINS: \(containsResults)")
            print("LIKE: \(likeResults)")
        } catch {
            print("Product model error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the first part of the answer the limitation is that you can't use it for numeric evaluations. I would suggest storing a string version of the number for the CONTAINS clause and a double property for other queries of functions (@SUM for example). The second part of the answer doesn't really go along with the question - I think the OP wants to return any object with the value of '10' in it... With that solution the IN query would have to list every possibility and that's an infinite number of possibilities 10,100,1000,10000 etc. Then what if the number is 1010 or 101010 etc.

Comment: @Jay Good call on storing both a Double and a String.

Comment: @Rob
The first solution I applied same solution. I Migrate my double value into a string and use contains operator.
The second solution Not relates to the question. From where these arrays come up. It's searching with string.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla No prob, I wasn't sure what your use cases were. I'll update my answer so it's more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As long as by `searchAmount` you are referring to the `searchValue: Double` argument in the `searchProductByAmount` func, printf syntax requires the `%f` symbol for double. `%@` is for object or string.

[As indicated here..](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)